# is it possible to run pyautogui on centos 7 docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, virtual-machine, centos7, pyautogui

I have an automation task that uses `pyautogui` and python3 to open a pdf and fill it out with predefined fields from JIRA (The pdf is locked down and there is no way to programatically interface with it other than `pyautogui`.) The script snaps to the top left of a screen where a pdf is opened, clicks in the pdf and then keystrokes are automated from there.

All of this works great on a desktop but now its time to put this on a server where it will run and the best option to deploy looks like Docker. Is what I'm suggesting possible or is there another method that will work like a docker-machine or VM ? This is my first deployment and it's small enough to really mess around with all possible options and do some good learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is, in general, not a good match for GUI applications.  In principle what you describe is possible, but if you're expecting a VM-like setup that can launch an X server, and the process you're trying to automate, and an automation program, an actual VM will work much better for this than Docker will.

That's doubly true if you already have a setup that can deploy your system on a clean Ubuntu desktop setup, or something along those lines; you should be able to deploy that almost as-is on a VM (maybe using a tool like [Packer](https://packer.io/) to automate building the VM image), but there will be a lot of "reinventing the wheel" and working around Docker's various limitations if you try to do this in Docker.  Even getting a container that can run the three steps of "launch an X server" and so on winds up being a not-my-first-Docker-project level of complicated.

Comment: Hey this helped me alot and saved me a ton of time instead of reinventing the wheel . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Built a container that uses xvfb and simulates the x11 session. Just need to set DISPLAY variable and create a session.

Comment: could you please describe your solution?